# Native tick sound on button clicks with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm handling the touchstart and touchend events to determine when an element is clicked. It works very well and is responsive, but I'm missing the default click sound that happens in native apps when you press a button.

Is there a way to trigger this sound with PhoneGap rather then using html5 audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Media class.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: The link is broken - should be updated!

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have developed new Cordova plugin a few days ago which provide that you need.

Take look at https://github.com/VVelda/device-feedback

You can then call native sound response on button click. No any audio media, or any other workaround. I hope it will help you, altough you already set the answer that help you. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much ! you plugin is just what i need. Clever solution to do native like sound in hybrid app.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @Velda! click-click-click

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post:
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/native-tick-sound-on-button-click-with-phonegap/

It explains how to develop a PhoneGap plugin that plays the native click sound when pressing a button in HTML5.

Comment: Hi, can you implement the iOS version too and publish it as a github/phonegap plugin, I'm sure many will use the plugin, I'm suprised no one developed it before, you can register it to plugreg afterwards, anyway thanks